# Reading data to table input pentaho

Tags: pentaho, data-warehouse, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, data-integration

I have questions. Maybe someone will help me. I have transformation as below
[image]

In Table_input I read data from the MSSQL database. In Table_input_2 i read data from DB2 database.
In Merge join I am comparing ID with each other and the rest of the attributes in the tables. In Filter rows I find the records on which the same ID is the difference. For now, I write the difference in the xlsx file. 
In Table_input and Table_input2 there are many records-over 100 mln. Often differences result from query execution times on MSSQL and DB2 databases.
I would like the process to be carried out again for the differences returned. I would like to be sure that the differences resulted from the time the query was completed. Can anyone give me a hint how to do it?

Comment: I'm afraid we need more information to answer this question. Can you elaborate more on what the steps do? In particular how are the rows merged and what does the filter do? You speak of an ID field that exists in both tables. I suppose this is an external ID and not an auto-increment field, right? If so, is this a field that can be used to exclusively identify an entry that may exists in both tables? Also what does this mean: "Often differences result from query execution times on MSSQL and DB2 databases"? How would the values of columns be dependent on the execution times of certain queries?

Comment: Are the differences happening because data lands in DB2 and MSSQL at different times or because the Pentaho queries take so long that data has already changed again in the other system?

Comment: Yes, the data have changed in the meantime. We replicate data from the MSSQL database to the DB2 database. And I check for differences between the MSSQL source database and the target DB2. The query takes a long time and in the meantime the data has already changed based on MSSQL. Hence the differences. And I would like the process to be done again, only for the discrepancies received.

Comment: Is Pentaho the one doing the replication or is Pentaho only verifying that some other replication is correct?

Comment: Pentaho only checks that replication is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your short description, you have two source databases that should be in sync, but aren't always. You are using this Pentaho job to find the differences, but when running you find false positives, differences that disappear in a short time due to the systems catching up again.

If you want to find differences that are persistent, your options depend on the circumstances of your operational systems.

If you're lucky, you have (or can get) [rowversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) from the MSSQL tables. These get updated when a row is changed. If the replication to DB2 includes these you know exactly whether you're comparing the same version of the row.

However, you likely wouldn't be asking here if you have the above already in place, so for now I'll assume you have to make do without reliable timestamps. Also, probably no quiet hours that see very few changes.

In your situation, I would process "small" rowsets of 10k, 100k or 1M rows at a time in the transformation and use a parent job to increased the starting ID each time. This reduces query times and hopefully differences.

You can see a complete example in one of my earlier answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58624138/6803853). It's slightly different because that one was for an offset/limit with unknown total records.

The idea is that your transformation takes parameters as input telling it at which ID to start and how many rows to take. Then it processes those and reports back either the number of records processed. If the last query got close to 0 records back, you're done. Due to realtime changes, it might not reach 0 exactly.

The parent job checks if you're done and if not updates the new START_ID and runs the transformation again.

Your Table inputs would change like this for DB2:

```
SELECT ...
FROM TABLE
WHERE ID >= ${START_ID} 
ORDER BY ID
LIMIT ${BATCH_SIZE}
```

and MSSQL (it's been a long time, may not be correct):

```
SELECT TOP ${BATCH_SIZE} ...
FROM TABLE
WHERE ID >= ${START_ID}
ORDER BY ID
```

If the ID is numerical, you can probably drop the Sort Rows steps in the transformation, saving a lot of time. If alphanumerical, keep them.

The Merge(diff) step does what you do in Merge Join and Filter rows, but needs identical field layout. Might be an option.

Finally, I would add Get System Info for a timestamp, then store any changed IDs in a table with the timestamp you detected them. Then report only on differences that persist for more than X minutes/hours/runs.